# Why do my calls hang up?

Tags: calls, google-pixel-2

Several times a week, the call suddenly ends and says "called ended."

That's it.

That's *all* the information my Pixel 2 gives me.

"Call ended."

Is it a cell network issue? Did the other side hang up? Did my phone think I pressed the hang up button? I cannot tell.

How do I get to the bottom of why my Pixel 2 sporadically hangs up?

The same thing happens to my wife's Pixel 2.

Comment: You could try //check call behavior in safe mode - if the problem persists, it is likely a network issue. If not, it's some installed app causing problems //Try  checking the behavior in a different location //Switch to 4G, instead of LTE// Check without  mobile data enabled //Try different SIM

Comment: Considering it's happening on both devices,  suggest reverse order of suggestions in comment above

Comment: Is the timing random? I have a similar experience on Nexus 5, LineageOS 14.1 (Android 7.1.2) with my local carrier that it will automatically hang up after around 1 hour.

Comment: @AndrewT Good point. One Indian carrier was accused (and rightly so) of this - reason is that they make revenue on call connecting, so incentive to drop the call :(  and force user to dial up again

Answer (score 0):

Turning OFF "Active Edge" and "Google Assistant" in Settings did the trick for me.  All those super-sensitive sensors were disrupting calls: wiggling the phone for better ear position, picking up speaker-phone call, switching ears, squeezing inadvertently during a call, all disrupted and hung up calls.  Turning off the settings, under "System" did the trick.